# Django default image not saving

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue while saving a default image whenever I am not uploading an image in ImageField. I can't understand what I am doing wrong, for me it seems everything ok but couldn't find where the bug is.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    fiscal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    license = models.ForeignKey(
        License, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, default='default.png')
    id_card = models.ForeignKey(
        IDCard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cap = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def create_student(request):
    context = {

    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        date_of_birth = request.POST.get('date_of_birth')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        cap = request.POST.get('cap')
        province = request.POST.get('province')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        fiscal_code = request.POST.get('fiscal_code')
        id_number = request.POST.get('id_number')
        expire_date = request.POST.get('expire_date')
        picture = request.FILES.get('picture')
        id_image = request.FILES.get('id_image')

        # fs = FileSystemStorage()
        # filename = fs.save(picture.name, picture)
        # profile_pic_url = fs.url(filename)
        # filename2 = fs.save(id_image.name, id_image)
        # id_image_url = fs.url(filename2)

        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
                username=username, password=password, email=email, last_name=last_name, first_name=first_name, user_type=3)
            user.student.address = address
            user.student.date_of_birth = date_of_birth
            user.student.cap = cap
            user.student.province = province
            user.student.country = country
            user.student.phone = phone
            user.student.fiscal_code = fiscal_code

            user.student.picture = picture

            user.save()

            id_card = IDCard.objects.create(
                number=id_number, expire_date=expire_date, picture=id_image)
            id_card.save()

            messages.success(request, "Successfully Added Student")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user:student_list'))
        except:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to Add Student")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user:create_student'))

    return render(request, 'user/create_student.html', context)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('user.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('student/', include('student.urls')),
    path('instructor/', include('instructor.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The view and the saving is just working fine. In fact, the images are saved properly. But when I try to leave the empty field in the image it doesn't provide the image 'default.png' (which I put inside the media folder).
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving only `User` object, not `Student` one.

views.py:

```
...
    user.student.picture = picture

    user.save()
    user.student.save()    # this will save student object to databse

    id_card = IDCard.objects.create(
        number=id_number, expire_date=expire_date, picture=id_image)
    id_card.save()    # this line does nothing, because object is saved in create() function
...
```

Another thing is you probably should not let Django save picture as None.

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    picture = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=False, default='default.png')
    ...
```

Comment: The student actually is saving, because I have a receiver in the models.py. My only issue here is that everything is working just fine, except the default picture, which is not uploading whenever I put an empty field in image field.

Comment: Ok, saving `Student` should be fine then. What if you change `null=True` to `False`? I think the problem might be in there (because you let the value to be `None`).

Comment: Yeah I tried but still doesn't work. I think I may have something wrong with the media folder or stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

1. Make sure you have `default.png` in your media file
2. In your view, you are retrieving your image file but it could be null and also your model allows the image to be null, in that case, you have to check if your request file image is null or not.

```py
picture = request.FILES.get('picture', None)
# Allowing null check
# Remove user.student.picture = picture and use the following
if picture:
    user.student.picture = picture
```

Same for your `id_image`

```py
id_image = request.FILES.get('id_image', None)
#...
# I assume id_image will also use default
id_card = IDCard(number=id_number, expire_date=expire_date, )
if id_image:
   id_card.picture=id_image
id_card.save()
```

Comment: Still the default image doesn't load. I think I am doing something wrong with my media folder but I can't find the issue. The media folder is in the same folder of the apps and the project

Comment: Do you have default.png in your media folder?

Comment: Yes I have it but I still have the issue. I tried even with different names (changing the name and migrating) but nothing

Answer (score 1):

I think the misunderstanding is in the "default" value: The default field value is only applied once at the moment of instantiation! Not when the instance is modified or saved.

I try to figure out what happens because some code is missing to be sure:

you instantiate a CustomUser and call the method create_user().

```
    user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
              username=username, password=password, email=email,last_name=last_name, first_name=first_name, user_type=3)
...
...
```

I suppose in create_user() you also instantiate the Student object ( that is the moment where the default is applied to student.picture!!) and assign it to CustomUser.student

later you assign

```
...       
            user.student.picture = picture
```

but the Student is already instantiated so if here you assign None, it will stay None. The default field value is only applied once at the moment of instantiation.

A solution could be to pass picture to the create_user() call and use it at the instantiation of the Student object.

Another option: only assign the picture if it is not None:

```
if picture is not None:
    user.student.picture = picture
```

Comment: Yeah I think that's the issue. Because the default image is currently applying to the other picture (the ID Card which is a Foreign Key). The only thing is, how can I solve this issue? Do I have to modify my model and apply the picture directly to the user or is there another way?

Comment: well you could ad the picture as parameter to create_user()  and assign it to the Student model when you instantiate it. Maybe post the creat_user() code here

Comment: other option added to the answer above at the end

Comment: After a long troubleshooting I found my issue. Was on the create_user instance in the models.py receiver (which, my bad, I didn't post in the first place). Thank you very much to everybody!!!